# СССР Parts Identification

Tags: capacitor, identification

I would really like to know what these are before I start playing around with them, tried to translate everything and can't find a thing — then again they say made in the USSR (СССР) so maybe no one knows?

```
    МБГО -2
   1 мкФ±10%ОТК
 300В  87 079
СДЕЛАНО В СССР [Made in the USSR]
```

(Transcription of the small one only.)

[image: Little one]
[image: big one]

Comment: I wonder if they are still functional after that many years

Comment: No, they went bust in 1991 after Solidarnosc and when the Berlin Wall fell.  It's weird, the Nazi war machine only made them stronger, but some Polish unionists were too much for em.

Comment: @Harper Luckily, Stalin didn't last till 1991.

Answer (score 58):

From [this page](http://asenergi.com/catalog/kondensatory-puskovye/mbgo.html) (in Russian), we can find that:

- МБГО stands for *конденсатор **м**еталло**б**умажный **г**ерметизированный **о**днослойный*, i.e. metal-paper hermetically sealed single-layer capacitor
- МБГО-1 differ from МБГО-2 by means of mounting: the latter ones have mounting elements on the case

1 мкФ is the Russian equivalent for 1 μF, while 300В means 300V. ±10% means that actual capacitance is within 10% of the nominal value.

If you try to search for description of Soviet parts on the Internet, you may want to look for Russian-language pages with the keyword of "маркировка", which means "marking", and use Google Translate to translate them into your language.

Answer (score 14):

This is a capacitor for 1 microfarad 300 volt

Comment: It is of paper-foil type.

Comment: You might want to add info for second capacitor from OP post to your answer (30μF, 160V)

Comment: You might want to add that 10% indicates the accuracy class: actual capacitance may be within the range of 0.9 to 1.1 microfarad.

Comment: I believe "±10%" is pretty self-explanatory

Answer (score 9):

Just use [Google translate](https://translate.google.com/#ru/en/%D0%9C%D0%91%D0%93%D0%9E-2%0A%20%20%201%20%D0%BC%D0%BA%D0%A4%C2%B110%25%D0%9E%D0%A2%D0%9A%0A%20300%D0%92%20%2087%20079%0A%D0%A1%D0%94%D0%95%D0%9B%D0%90%D0%9D%D0%9E%20%D0%92%20%D0%A1%D0%A1%D0%A1%D0%A0), it will happily translate units for you:

[image]